# How to implement a cross-table global unique ID in MySQL5 (for comments assignment)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have several db-tables which have completely distinct fields for different types of information. These tables represent different categories of data in an application front-end. I'd like to implement a comment feature for all of these datasets, no matter what category (db-table) they are in.

So i'd set up a "comments" table where every entry would be assigned to a certain dataset as an 1:n relation. Of course this wouldn't be a problem at all if all the data would be stored in single table but how can i solve this with the data being stored in multiple tables, as i only have per-table unique id's? I'd need some kind of a global ID for all of the tables.

I was thinking about a specific table (something like "glob_id, table, id") for the assignment of global unique id's, but i'm stuck in finding a way assigning tables an corresponding id's to the unique global id.

Any attempts, how to solve this? 
Is this a good approach?
Any different approaches?

I'd like to solve this at the database level, if possible.

Comment: Why are you trying to get all the comments into a single table?  The more natural way is to put the comments in with the original data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not go down the road of using a GUID / UID / Global Unique Identifier.
Instead I would create mapping tables between the main message table and the individual table that stores the entity to comment against.

Each insert into the comments table would have an ID that ID would then be inserted into the mapping table that contains the ID of the original entity to comment against and the comment ID.

For example

**product**:

```
id
name
```

**product_comments**

```
product_id
comment_id
```

**anothertable**

```
id
anothervalue
```

**anothertable_comments**

```
some_id
comment_id
```

**comments table**

```
id
comment
```

The reason I would use a mapping table is because you would be required to create a new global identifier in each of your existing tables.  The mapping table would also allow a many – many as well as a one to one relationship so someone could apply the same comment to more than one existing table.

**Edit:**

Single mapping table:

If there are lots of tables you want to add this to you can just create a single mapping table. For example:

**comments_table**

```
id
comment
```

**table_map**

```
table_name
table_id
comment_id
```

This way you would add the table name and the id of the row along with the comment id to this single mapping table.  This reduces the number of tables you have to insert but you must then think about appropriate indexing for performance reasons as you don’t want to do a full table scan on mapping tables.

Comment: Thanks, Steve. Your approach seems reasonable to me, although it goes along with a whole lot more tables in the database. If i won't find a way to somehow map table and id inside of one global-id-table i will follow your approach.